# PHP explode the string and concate the first character of each word

Tags: php

I have a Person Name in a variable `$contactnamefield`. Example: Justin Cruise.
I want to pick the first character of Justin 'J' and C of Cruise and then combine it and Save it in a variable `$username = 'JC'`.

Comment: Your title seems to answer the question. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
   $name = "John A Doe";
   $parts = explode(' ',$name);
   $initials = '';
   foreach($parts as $part) {
      $initials .= $part[0];
   }
   echo $initials;
?>
```

This should work. It gets the first letter of each part, not just the first and last. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want since you only gave a name clause of first and last name, not sure how you want to handle middle names.

Comment: Thanks. Its working great!. As its a unique field in the table so if the other person has also the same name what do to in that case? I want that to be JAD2..

Comment: Setup a second table where you store initials and the count. Increment the count each time the same initials are used, and use the count number appended to the end of the initials in the user table.